# How to align the contents left side of a full-width container relative to a fixed-width container

Tags: css, sass, containers, fluid-layout, fixed-width

I have a problem with the left indent for the .col-sm-4
Unable to align its content relative to the container with a fixed width.

```
    .container {       
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;  
    }
    
    .fluid-cintainer {       
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;  
    }
```

HTML

```
<main>
      <div class="container"></div>
      <div class="fluid-cintainer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-8"><img src="" alt="Full width of .col-sm-8"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

What you've actually done is close the `.container` class too early.

You need to have your Fluid-cintainer inside your `.container` class.

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fluid-cintainer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

This will make your CSS work

Comment: I tried this way but it does not suit me, as the image must stretch across the width of the .col-sm-8.